# Making a custom shift function to lag a dataframe with missing observations

Tags: pandas

So some of the periods are missing in my dataframe but I still want to be able to shift the data appropriately. This is what I have written

```
def custom_lag(df, lag_distance, columns_to_lag, reference_column):
    shape = np.zeros((len(df),len(columns_to_lag)))
    new_cols_prefix = "lag"+str(lag_distance)+"_"
    new_cols = [new_cols_prefix + col for col in columns_to_lag]
    lagged_df = pd.DataFrame(shape, index=df.index, columns=new_cols)

    ref = df[reference_column]
    for index, time in zip(ref.index, ref.values):
        desired_row = df[ref == time+lag_distance]
        lagged_df.loc[index, new_cols] = desired_row[columns_to_lag].to_numpy() if len(desired_row) != 0 else [np.nan]*len(new_cols)
    return lagged_df[new_cols]

df.groupby('id').apply(custom_lag, 1, ['prc'], 'period')
```

But unfortunately this returns a multidex with duplicates. I'd like to be like the official shift function where I can just assign the new columns back into my original dataframe.

Ideas for how to fix this?

If there's a better solution I'm all ears. This runs quite a bit slower than I as hoping for.

Here's an example of a what df might look like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
              'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,
                   2,2,2,2,
                   3,3,3],
              'period':[1,2,3,5,6,7,
                       2,4,6,7,
                       1,2,3],
              'prc':[5,4,6,5,4,2,
                     8,7,6,5,
                    6,3,4]})
```

Which will look lke

```
    id  period  prc
0    1       1    5
1    1       2    4
2    1       3    6
3    1       5    5
4    1       6    4
5    1       7    2
6    2       2    8
7    2       4    7
8    2       6    6
9    2       7    5
10   3       1    6
11   3       2    3
12   3       3    4
```

see how there are missing period data? That's what makes regular shift undesirable.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
# create lagged col
df['lag_prc'] = df.groupby('id')['prc'].shift(-1)

# set values as NA if period differs by 1
df['lag_prc'] = (df['period']
                 .shift(-1)
                 .sub(df['period'])
                 .eq(1)
                 .mul(1)
                 .replace(0, np.nan) * df['lag_prc'])

print(df)

    period  id  prc  lag_prc
0        1   1    5      4.0
1        2   1    4      6.0
2        3   1    6      NaN
3        5   1    5      4.0
4        6   1    4      2.0
5        7   1    2      NaN
6        2   2    8      NaN
7        4   2    7      NaN
8        6   2    6      5.0
9        7   2    5      NaN
10       1   3    6      3.0
11       2   3    3      4.0
12       3   3    4      NaN
```

Comment: That's close! But the missing periods make it so I can't do that unfortunately. So I have to figure out how to run some logic within the groupby

Comment: just noticed, fixing it.

Comment: Very clever. I'm still making sure it works but  I think this is it!

Comment: So unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for a generalized lag. I'll make a new post